# How to pass the value for one aspx to another aspx page

Tags: asp.net

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>

     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="RedirectPage" PostBackUrl="~/TestAjaxControls.aspx?FirstName=txtFirstName&LastName=txtLastName"  />
</div>

</form>
```

I need to access the firstname & lastname value to the next page

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property. Or Save values into [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**PreviousPage**

To find prevoius page's controls, you can use FindControl function

```
TextBox txtFirstName = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
```

**Session**

Save control values into session:

```
Session["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
```

And from any page you can get session value:

```
string firstName = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Properies from commmon code:

```
public class Employee
{
    string _name;

public string Name
{
get
{
    // Return the actual name if it is not null.
    return this._name ?? string.Empty;
}
set
{
    // Set the employee name field.
    this._name = value;
}
}
}
```

Or Use Session a very handy and easy way

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the query string.

```
Response.Redirect("~/nextpage.aspx?firstName=" + txtFirstName.Text + "&lastName=" + txtLastName.Text);
```

You will need to add validation.

I recommend avoid using the session as it could be an overkill for something like this, and if you do however, you will have to clear the session properly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do the redirect on button OnClick, with the parameters in QueryString like you tried:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="RedirectPage" OnClick="Redirect_Click" />
```

and:

```
protected void Redirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstN =txtFirstName.Text;
    string lastN =txtLastName.Text;
    string redirectUrl = String.Format("~/TestAjaxControls.aspx?FirstName={0}&LastName={1}", firstN, lastN);
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```